# Broadcast Receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED on API >= 23

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

Currently I've this in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    ...

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.LockerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This does not work on **APIs >= 23**. there's no boot event received ever.
Now. Since Marshmallow most of the permissions should be asked runtime. But how can I do it if what I want to permit is to receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event?

If I use

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

it appears to work, but should I do something else to ask the permission?

Comment: According to the documentation, it is a Normal permission, so you should only declare it in the Manifest file from what I can see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html